# How to setup "Enable Express" of ServiceBus in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit, saga, automatonymous

Is there any way to control "**Enable express**" option of **Azure ServiceBus** in **MassTransit**?

I've found other options like "**Enable Partitioning**", "**Enable Batched Operations**" but not this one.
According to google search results it seems like it was supported.
Also I've found commented out line in sources of massTransit test.

```
            configurator.Publish<PartitionedMessage>(x =>
            {
                x.EnablePartitioning = true;
                //x.EnableExpress = true;
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Azure v7 SDK (first integrated with MassTransit v7.3.0), the ability to create an express queue or subscription was removed.